# UEFI installing Fedora 17 after Windows 8

Tags: multi-boot, fedora, bootloader, uefi

I recently bought an HP Pavilion G6-2313AX laptop which ships with FreeDOS.

I first partitioned it with old Ubuntu live disk to partition (I didn't have GParted CD on hand). There was an existing partition of 900MB `EFI System Partition` . I don't know why this partition is required as the laptop doesn't ship with Windows 8 preinstalled. However I didn't delete that partition, I was afraid I've never heard of such beast. The Windows 8 installation went just fine.

Now I am trying to install Fedora 17 on another primary partition next to the Windows 8 NTFS partition.

It's is giving an error after Partition manager -> Next.

```
you have not created a bootloader stage1 target device
sdb2 must have one of the following disklabel types: gpt
```

I am ready to start from beginning. Should I install Fedora 18 instead? Should I delete that EFI System Partition or should I format and mount it as `/boot/efi`?

and what will happen If I delete `EFI System Partition` ?

**Edit**

I just checked My BIOS. I saw **`Legacy Support`** was `enabled` 
Now If Legacy support is `enabled` from factory for a `FreeDOS` Laptop. Why would it have an `EFI System Partition` and what would that `EFI System Partition` contain ?
So is that EFI System Partition useless ? is it safe to delete it ?

I am totally confused.

Comment: would that give me any benefit on this problem ?

Comment: @user36582 - Yes.  Your problem is your using an older version of the Fedora.

Comment: Fedora 20 giving `Error Checking storage configuration after partitioning`

Answer (score 0):

The first error is a well-known problem with the Fedora installer. It is just a bug: [see here](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Common_F19_bugs#Apple_EFI_Macs:_EFI_install_alongside_existing_EFI_installed_OS_.28including_OS_X.29_results_in_you_have_not_created_a_bootloader_stage1_target_device_error). Curiously, the bug is reported for Fedora 19, and a pre-existing installation of a MacOS, not of Windows. Yet its description fits perfectly your case:

> If you try to do a native UEFI install of Fedora 19 alongside a native UEFI install of OS X and re-use the existing EFI system partition, the installer will incorrectly consider the existing EFI system partition as invalid and report that you have not created a bootloader stage1 target device. Unfortunately, the Fedora automatic partitioning algorithm will actually attempt to re-use the EFI system partition, and so you will run into this bug in any Fedora 19 installation attempt where you use the automatic partitioning algorithm and do not choose to delete the existing EFI system partition.
>
> Practically speaking, there are a few different approaches to dealing with this problem. If you do not mind losing your OS X installation, you can simply choose to delete it (including the EFI system partition), and let Fedora occupy the rest of the disk. Fedora should create a new EFI system partition and install successfully.
>
> If you wish to preserve your OS X installation, install Fedora 19 Final, and dual boot, you must use the installer's 'custom partitioning' path. Make sure to leave the existing EFI system partition intact, but do not set a mount point for it. Do not use the Create partitions for me button. Instead, manually create a new EFI system partition, and set it to be mounted at /boot/efi. Manually create other partitions as usual. Complete custom partitioning, and your installation should proceed successfully. See the Installation Guide for general instructions on the partitioning process, if necessary.
>
> You could also try installing Fedora 18 or Fedora 19 Beta. These should allow you to use automatic partitioning to install alongside OS X, assuming you do not run into any other bugs they may have contained. You could then upgrade to Fedora 19 Final - with FedUp from Fedora 18, or yum from Fedora 19 Beta. You will still wind up with two EFI system partitions in this case.

In this light, I strongly urge you to install Fedora 20, as already suggested by @karel, because it might just happen the bug has been corrected there. Just might.

As for the second error, I suspect it stems from the first one, since it appears to say that you do not have a GPT partition table, which jibes nicely with the bug above. Also, I would make sure that your BIOS is set to UEFI mode, **not** legacy BIOS.

> We are investigating the possibility of producing an updates image to make it easier to deal with this bug. We apologize for any inconvenience it causes you.

Comment: getting `Error Checking storage configuration` after partitioning

Comment: If he is booting in UEFI mode, into windows 8, then he has a GPT partition.

Comment: You must create a GPT partition table, like stated above. Or, you choose Legacy Bios mode inside your BIOS, in which case you will have to re-install Windows.

Comment: Can I create GPT partition table with GParted Live CD ? I dont see any such option there

Comment: @Ramhound how to confirm that I have a GPT partition ? I've used GParted Live CD Stable version, and I'vent seen anything like GPT. there was a `boot` flag but is that GPT ? I looks like partition table is of `msdos` type. and as I mentioned in question I didn't have Windows 8 pre installed. It came with FreeDOS pre-installed.

Comment: msdos indicates you have a MBR

Comment: can there be MBR as well as `EFI System Partition` ?

Comment: @user36582 Yes, it is a protective MBR. To prevent damage to the disk from non-UEFI-aware programs.

Comment: So should I delete `EFI System Partition` ?

Comment: also If I change the partition table to gpt. I think I've to delete the existing `EFI System Partition`